# Limitar el valor de una celda

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, grid

estoy trabajando con un proyecto en wpf asp.net. Tengo un grid y quiero que una de las celdas nunca pueda superar cierto valor, en concreto 99.99. Esta celda puede ser editada por el usuario. He probado a usar MaxValue pero da error siempre. Otra cosa que he pensado usar es un StringFormat, pero no sé muy bien cómo usarlo.

Aquí dejo una parte del código

```
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="columnPropiedad"
                     Width="*"
                     Binding="{Binding Path=Propiedad, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
                               Converter={StaticResource formatConverter},
                               ConverterParameter=\{0:n2\}}">
                     <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                                 <TextBlock Text="Nombre de la columna" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

No sé cómo, pero creo que modificando el **ConverterParameter** se puede limitar el valor de la celda.

¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

Si no desea usar DatagridTemplateColumn, puede cambiar DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyley establecer TextBox.MaxLengthallí:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=SellingPrice, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
 <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="10"/>
   </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Podrias provar con esto

Comment: Vale, esto me controla la longitud de la parte entera del número pero no me deja modificar la parte decimal, ¿alguna idea?